# injected variables null in UntypedActor Play 2.5 java

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, akka, actor

On this moment I'm dealing with a tricky problem. For my API I was hoping to use Play and Akka actor. The problem I'm having is that every object I try to inject in my Actor remains null. One solution is to inject this object in the controller and than pass it on to my actor but this is not what I want to do. I want my object only on the place where I need it.

```
package actors;

import actors.Messages.GetAanleverAfspraakById;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

import model.domain.AanleverAfspraakDO;
import play.db.jpa.JPAApi;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by harms.h on 22-03-2016.
 */
public class AfspraakActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Inject
    private JPAApi api;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message instanceof GetAanleverAfspraakById){
            final AanleverAfspraakDO aanleverAfspraakDO = this.getAanleverAfspraakDO(((GetAanleverAfspraakById) message).getId());
            getSender().tell(aanleverAfspraakDO, getSelf());
        }
        else{
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }

    private AanleverAfspraakDO getAanleverAfspraakDO(int id){
        final AanleverAfspraakDO aanleverAfspraakDO = api.withTransaction(() -> {
            final Query query = api.em().createNamedQuery("findbyid").setParameter("id", id);
            final Collection<AanleverAfspraakDO> resultSet = query.getResultList();
            final AanleverAfspraakDO result = resultSet.iterator().next();
            return result;
        });

        return aanleverAfspraakDO;
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now I used the following code after a long search on the internet

```
this.api = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(JPAApi.class);
```

I'm not sure if this is a clean solution what do you guys think?

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran into the same issue and jpaapi is not being injected for some reason. The above statement is working okay and I got unblocked for now.

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.5: Create the following class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.actor.Actor;
import akka.actor.IndirectActorProducer;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import play.api.Play;

public class GenericDependencyInjector implements IndirectActorProducer {

   final Class<? extends UntypedActor> actorClass;

   @Inject
   public GenericDependencyInjector(Class<? extends UntypedActor> actorClass) {
      this.actorClass = actorClass;
   }

   @Override
   public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
      return actorClass;
   }

   @Override
   public Actor produce() {
      return Play.current().injector().instanceOf(actorClass);
   }
}
```

Then when you create the actor, pass the GenericDependencyInjector along with your Service Interface:

```
final Props props = Props.create(GenericDependencyInjector.class, JPAApi.class);
context().actorOf(props);
```

Now you should be able inject your services into the actor with ease.